# Use the setUserVisibleHint for videoView in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, video, android-viewpager

I'm done with making the video player which plays the video from url. The only problem is that I'm using ViewPager in which different pages are there one of them is this also. So the thing is that if I don't use the **setUserVisibleHint()** there are two problems which comes up these are :

- The video doesn't stop playing until I switch to third page.
- The mediacontroller, if visible and if we switch to the next page the media controller is visible in the net page also, until it is gone.

Right now my code is this :

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private VideoView mVideoView;
private ProgressBar mProgress;
private MediaController mMediaController;

private String url = null;
private Uri uri = null;

public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    url = "xyz";

    uri = Uri.parse(url);

    mVideoView = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.homeVideoView);
    mVideoView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    mProgress = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.homeSpinner);
    mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    mMediaController = new MediaController(getContext());
    getActivity().getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    loadVideos();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(isVisibleToUser){
        //loading cart elements
    }else{
        Log.e("NOT", "VISIBLE");
    }
}

//load the videos in the home fragment
private void loadVideos() {

    try {

        mVideoView.setMediaController(mMediaController);
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        mVideoView.requestFocus();

        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();

                //handling the progressBar for buffering and ending it
                mp.setOnInfoListener(new MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
                        if(MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START == i){
                            mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            mp.start();
                        }
                        if (MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START == i){
                            mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        if(MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END == i){
                            mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("VIDEO PLAYER ERROR", e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

What I've tried are :

- Declaring the **loadVideo()** in my the isVisibleToUser Case, but go this problem saying,

  VIDEO PLAYER EXCEPTION : Could not set MedialController to a null object reference and the progressBar load infinitely.
- Removed all the things from the loadVideos() and let the **setOnPReparedListener()** be there but this also gave me an Exception saying

  `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.VideoView.setOnPreparedListener(android.media.MediaPlayer$OnPreparedListener)' on a null object reference`

*The app crashed saying that mVideoView.stopPlayBack() is getting called on null object reference after doing this*

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(isVisibleToUser){
        //loading cart elements
        mVideoView.start();
    }else{
        Log.e("NOT", "VISIBLE");
        mVideoView.stopPalyBack();
    }
}
```

**NOTE : This page is the first page which loads up when the app opens up and hence condition goes to else condition for sometime before the actual visibility of the page in setUSerVisibleHint()**

**Video url is tested on the video view itself so it is just that to deal with the viewPager stuff.**

Finally after a lot of efforts I resumed the code as it is and lets the mind take some rest after a long research. The full code above needs to be amended. Any suggestions would highly be appreciated! Thanks